# VBA Copy & paste chart in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Im trying to copy a graph from on sheet when a condition is met. For example

> IF range ("G5") = "Team 1" Then
>
> Copy and Paste Graph at range (H15:N31)
>
> Then remove the graph when the work sheet is exited  or another team
>   is selected.

Any ideas on the VBA code i would need to make this happen.

I have attempted to use INDEX & MATCH fomrulas to populate a graph on the same sheet then hide the columns however this has not worked usually end up with N/a.

I have also seen various segments of code on the internet however dont fully understand how they have done what im asking.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: what do you mean with `Graph`?? just `Shapes`, `Charts` or anythign similar?? What for did you try to use index and match formula, I don't get that idea.

Comment: I attempted to use the index and match to bring the information to the sheet where i need the chart displayed. therefore build the chart on the same page. But if you have any ideas of ways to make this better then it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been sorted now. I decided to go back and try INDEX & Match again see if i could get it to work. I found where i went wrong.

Before the data was fairly scattered and the way i was referencing it was a fairly bad method. (This was after a really bad day and i couldn't concentrate any longer hence asking everyone here).

I rearranged the data into three separate categories on the sheet i was indexing. Then i placed each team number next to the relevant data set for example:

```
      Productivity
Team 1 43.56%
Team 2 58.89%
Team 3 blah
Team 4 blah
```

Then on the page where im building the chart i used the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Team Overview'!S18:S21,(MATCH('Individual Overview'!G5,'Team Overview'!R18:R21,0)),1),0)
```

Then when i used the index and match formula again. This time when the team number was selected the chart generated the data correctly. All  the numbers corresponded with the appropriate team and it now works a treat.